# how to pass clicked item data to another activity

Tags: android

I have todolist app and it works fine.I can add and edit item to list view successfully. Here is my problem.When i click item,item's data have to pass edit activity but now it is empty like adding new item.What can ı do?

editItem.java

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_item);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.prioritySpinner);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.statusbutton);
    editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editButton);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

    editButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

            task = editText1.getText().toString();
            priorityLevel = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            status = toggleButton.getText().toString();

            int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
            int year = datePicker.getYear();

            date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

            itemList.setName(task);
            itemList.setPriorityLevel(priorityLevel);
            itemList.setStatus(status);
            itemList.setDueDate(date);

            Intent okIntent = new Intent();
            okIntent.putExtra("editItem", new DataWrapper(itemList));

            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, okIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement your itemList class from Serializable interface,

```
public class ItemList implements Serializable {
// your class
}
```

and then use in first activity:

```
okIntent.putExtra("editItem", itemList);
```

in second activity, to get intent data:

```
ListItem listItem = (ListItem) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("editItem");
```

Comment: yes,it seriazizable.my problem when i click added item Editıtem class run and it is empty.item's data have to pass this class from listview so user can edit item.

Comment: try to initialize fully your editItem.
`DataWraper dataWraper = new DataWraper(itemList);`
and then put it to intent extras.
Also I didn't notice in your code when you are initializing your itemList variable. Maybe you forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

When starting your edit `Activity` you should pass in some extra edit data.

Assuming your `DataWrapper` class can be used as 'extra', so it should extend `Parcelable` or `Serializable`. (Preferably use `Parcelable` because its **faster and designed for Android**, of course `Serializable` can be used but i don't recommend it)

Here is an example of adding some arguments to the `Activity` start `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), edititem.class);
i.putExtra("editdata",new DataWrapper(clickeditem));
startActivityForResult(i);
```

Then in the edititem `Activity` get the data using:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    //Edit mode
    DataWrapper value = extras.getParcelable("editdata"); //Or extras.getSerializable("editdata");
} else {
    //New mode
}
```

Rolf

Comment: yes,dataWrapper class serializable.I can get editted data.When i click   added item EditItem activity run and clicked item's data dont pass here.It has to show selected items data such as task,date so user can edit it

Comment: Have you tried addig the code from my answer to your project. If you did and its still not working please post the complet code from both the activities. So I can help you further.